# Upgrade Firmwares for Lenovo servers for SLES12

Tags: sles

```
SERVER:/opt/OneCli # cd /opt/OneCli; ./OneCli update acquire --mt 6241 --ostype sles12 --dir ./firmware/ --output ./output

Lenovo XClarity Essentials OneCLI lxce_onecli02c-2.1.0
Licensed Materials - Property of Lenovo
(C) Copyright Lenovo Corp. 2013-2017 All Rights Reserved
Start to download from Lenovo......

Acquiring list of updates for Machine-Type=6241 OS="SLES 12"...
Failed to run acquire command
SERVER:/opt/OneCli #
SERVER:/opt/OneCli # cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 2
# This file is deprecated and will be removed in a future service pack or release.
# Please check /etc/os-release for details about this release.
SERVER:/opt/OneCli #
```

#### Question

This worked for SLES11 and SLES12 was released 4 years ago. What am I missing?

**NOTE:** The [man page](http://toolscenter.lenovofiles.com/help/topic/toolsctr_cli_lenovo/onecli_r_acquire_command.html) doesn't says anything extra. Using [this version](https://download.lenovo.com/servers/mig/2017/11/14/17848/lnvgy_utl_lxce_onecli02c-2.1.0_sles12_x86-64.tgz), for SLES11 we always used [this version](https://download.lenovo.com/servers/mig/2017/11/14/17847/lnvgy_utl_lxce_onecli02c-2.1.0_sles11_x86-64.tgz).